# finds the maximum number of overlapping sections

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, algorithm

Assume you receive a set of sections on X axis.

A section has an ID , a start point and an end point 
Write pseudo code or actual code that finds the maximum number of overlapping sections and their IDs

Describe the data structure or the class you are using to represent the data .

Comment: Ok, what have your tried **yourself**?

Comment: I been asked this question on the interview . I believe it is standard  3 year  algorithm question . I believe it should be solved with greedy algorithm for event scheduling or divide and concur algorithm . I am still working on it .

Comment: Good. come back when you have decided on the language you use and when you have run into problems with your solution.

Comment: does my answer helped you? If not I may edit it...

Answer (score 0):

The data structure I would use is [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)
It's no matter of what language you use.

For the class to represent the data, it is asking you to outline the node design of the segment tree.

```
struct node{
    int L,R,v; // the end point and the # of segments lying in this interval, init = 0
}
```

Then for each segment, run a range update operation (total `O(N lg(N))`)

I think there is a need to lazy propagate while updating

Then sort the end points, and then query the `2N-1` "gap" between these end points (For eg: Given [1,3], [2,5], I would query [1,2] , [2,3], [3,5])
(total `O(N lg(N))`)

Lastly, you should about to know which "gap" contains the maximum # of overlapping segments, to find the ID of those segments, just `O(N)` to check if each segment intersect with that "gap"

I am quite new to segment tree, but I hope I can give you a correct direction :)

**EDITED:**

1. I think it's possible to have multiple solution for the IDs, I assume you can output anyone of them
2. How to handle the touch case (i.e. [1,3],[3,5]) is problem related, normally it is considered as maximum of 2 overlapping at coordinate 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a blind shot because it does not say if the key is performance, clarity, etc. In C#, let's assume that a Section is an object like

```cs
class Section
{
public double StartX;
public double EndX;
public int ID;
//[...]
}
```

Then I need an external class to get the overlaps (let's assume that a section can overlap with several other sections and each overlap must be counted independenly)

```cs
 class OverlapCounter
        {
            public static int GetOverlaps(Section[] inputSections, out List<int> OverlappedSectionsIDs)
            {
                int numOverlaps = 0;
                OverlappedSectionsIDs = new List<int>();
                for (int i= inputSections.Length-1; i>=1; i--)
                {
                    bool isNotListed = true;

                    double S1_start = inputSections[i].StartX;
                    double S1_end= inputSections[i].EndX;

                    for (int j= i-1; j>=0; j--)                     
                    {
                        double S2_start = inputSections[j].StartX; //stored for the sake of clarity
                        double S2_end = inputSections[j].EndX;

                        if (S1_start<= S2_end && S1_end>= S2_start) 
                        {
                            numOverlaps++; //all the overlappings are counted
                            if(isNotListed)
                            {
                                //IDs should not be repeated
                                OverlappedSectionsIDs.Add(inputSections[i].ID); 
                                isNotListed = false;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }

                return numOverlaps;
            }
        }
```

Finally, you can get what is asked with:

```cs
    List<int> OverlappedSectionsIDs;
    int numMaxOverlaps = OverlapCounter.GetOverlaps(SectionsArray,out OverlappedSectionsIDs);
```